# Receiving Segmentation fault (core dumped) in the following lex/yacc files. What is wrong with them?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I'm getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) for the following codes :

The lex file is as follows, 
test.l :

```
    %{

    #include "y.tab.h"

    #define LOOKUP 0

    int state;

    int add_word(int type, char *word);
    int lookup_word(char *word);
    %}

    %%

    \n {state = LOOKUP;}
    \.\n {state = LOOKUP;
            return 0;
        }

    ^verb {state = VERB;}
    ^adj {state = ADJECTIVE;}
    ^adv {state = ADVERB;}
    ^noun {state = NOUN;}
    ^prep {state = PREPOSITION;}
    ^pron {state = PRONOUN;}
    ^conj {state = CONJUNCTION;}

    [a-zA-Z]+ {
                if(state != LOOKUP){
                    add_word(state, yytext);
                }else{
                    switch(lookup_word(yytext)){
                        case VERB: return(VERB);
                        case ADJECTIVE: return(ADJECTIVE);
                        case ADVERB: return(ADVERB);
                        case NOUN: return(NOUN);
                        case PREPOSITION: return(PREPOSITION);
                        case PRONOUN: return(PRONOUN);
                        case CONJUNCTION: return(CONJUNCTION);
                        default:
                            printf("%s: don't recog\n",yytext);
                    }
                }
                }
    . ;

    %%
    struct word{
        char *word_name;
        int word_type;
        struct word *next;
    };

    struct word *word_list;

    extern void *malloc();

    int add_word(int type, char *word){
        struct word *wp;
        if(lookup_word(word) != LOOKUP){
            printf("word %s already defined\n", word);
            return 0;
        }

        wp = (struct word *) malloc(sizeof(struct word));

        wp-> next = word_list;

        wp-> word_name = (char*) malloc(strlen(word)+1);
        strcpy(wp->word_name, word);
        wp->word_type = type;
        word_list = wp;
        return 1;
    }

    int lookup_word(char *word){
        struct word *wp = word_list;

        for(; wp; wp = wp->next){
        if(strcmp(wp->word_name, word) == 0)
            return wp->word_type;
        }
        return LOOKUP;
    }
```

The yacc file is as follows,

test.y:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>

%}

%token NOUN PRONOUN VERB ADVERB ADJECTIVE PREPOSITION CONJUNCTION

%%
sentence: subject VERB object {printf("sentence is valid\n");}
        ;

subject: NOUN
        | PRONOUN
        ;
object: NOUN
        ;

%%

extern FILE *yyin;

main(){ 
    while(!feof(yyin)){
        yyparse();
    }
}

yyerror(s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "some error\n");
}
```

I've been trying for hours to figure out what is the problem. I am completely new with these and following the book "O'reilly - Lex and Yacc".

Comment: Don't provide you own prototype declaration of standard functions, include the correct header files instead. Also please read [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: As for your problem, if you run in a debugger where does the crash happens? Is your code in the call stack? And please edit your question to include the input you provide to cause the crash.

Comment: @melpomene thanks a lot! removing the feof() worked like a charm!!!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i'm still a beginner when it comes to gdb so i really don't know how to trace the crash.

Comment: @user3470048 If that fixed the problem, then `yyin` was probably not initialized yet (presumably the call to `yyparse` does that?).

Comment: You need to update your books, `yyerror(s)` this style of function declaration is discouraged for the last 20 years at least

Comment: @melpomene that could be it. 
Now i'm facing another problem, inputting same sentence twice creates an error. i should try using gdb.

Comment: @n.m. The book i have is from 1991. god that's old!!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably still using pre-standard C. The first C standard came out in 1989/1990 (ANSI/ISO version, respectively).

Comment: I used gdb and @melpomene , you were right, 
(gdb) print yyin
$1 = (FILE *) 0x0
so it means yyin is not getting initialized!
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You might want to consider using the book "Flex and Bison" also by Levine.  It was published in 2009 and uses the GNU variants of lex and yacc.

Comment: thank @MichaelBurr ! i will give it a try!

Comment: And when you're provided with an error message in `yyerror()`, don't just ignore it and mindlessly print `"some error'"`. Print the one you're given in the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanner generated by (f)lex, which is the component responsible for performing the input, initializes `yyin` and `yyout` to `stdin` and `stdout`, respectively, during its initialization function. Before that, they are both NULL pointers, as a result of C's static initialization rule (which is that global pointer variables are initialized to NULL.)

The initialization function is called the first time `yylex` is called. (It sets a flag so that the next call to `yylex` does not do the initialization again. That's a very typical approach to initializing library systems; most `malloc` implementations and some implementations of the C `stdio` functions do the same thing.)

`yylex` is called repeatedly by `yyparse`, so the first call to `yyparse` implicitly initializes `yylex`. But when you write:

```
main(){ 
  while(!feof(yyin)){
    yyparse();
  }
}
```

the first use of `yyin` occurs before it has been initialized. Consequently, the first time the `while` condition is evaluated, `yyin` is still `NULL` and therefore there is no second time; the resulting segfault is fatal.

You could fix that by initializing `yyin` yourself, but since *`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong* (sm), it would make more sense to put the EOF test at the *end* of the loop:

```
int main(){ 
  do yyparse(); while (!feof(yyin));
}
```

See [this very helpful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) to the question *Why is “`while ( !feof (file) )`” always wrong?* for a detailed analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes more sense now :D